# How to make composite component similar to <h:selectOneRadio />

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have been searching a lot for a way to make a composite component similar to: `<h:selectOneRadio />`
but I did not succeed.

I want something like:

```
<myowntags:selectOneRadio>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value0" itemLabel="This is the value 0" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value1" itemLabel="This is the value 1" />
  <f:selectItem itemValue="value2" itemLabel="This is the value 2" />
</myowntags:selectOneRadio>
```

and:

```
<myowntags:selectOneRadio>
  <f:selectItems  value="#{controller.items}"  />
</myowntags:selectOneRadio>
```

As you can see, I want this composite component to have a child: `<f:selectItem />` and render it the way I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check and iterate over them by `#{cc.children}`. The `#{cc}` refers to the current composite [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) instance which in turn has a [`getChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getChildren%28%29) method. You could do kind of an `instanceof` check by checking the child's FQN (or simple name if that's sufficient) in the `<cc:implementation>`:

```
<c:forEach items="#{cc.children}" var="child">
    <c:set var="type" value="#{child['class'].simpleName}" />
    <c:if test="#{type == 'UISelectItem'}">
        <input type="radio" value="#{child.itemValue}" />#{child.itemLabel}<br/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="#{type == 'UISelectItems'}">
        <c:forEach items="#{child.value}" var="item">
            <input type="radio" value="#{item.value}" />#{item.label}<br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Your next problem is however collecting the submitted values. For that you'd need to implement the `decode()` method in the backing `UIComponent` which you reference by `<cc:interface componentType>`. Or, better, create a custom `UIComponent` with a `Renderer` instead. Taking over the `Renderer`'s job in the view is clumsy.